# Why can't complexity of ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size() be constant?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, nonblocking, concurrent-queue

[Javadoc for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#size--) explicitly states that the complexity of the size() method is O(n). I find this surprising. I would follow the stock `LinkedList.size()` approach by accumulating the size in a counter. Given the asynchronous nature of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`'s operations, naturally the counter would have to be `AtomicInteger`. Was this not done because it would run against the non-blocking guarantees? If so, how much of an overhead should I expect the `AtomicInteger` counter to introduce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `AtomicInteger`: it's a good thing to use in a non-blocking environment. However, if you added an `AtomicInteger` counter to the queue, you would introduce a place which both `pool()` and `offer(E)` have to keep updated. That would increase the number of CAS operations as well as the number of *failed* CAS operations.

The Javadoc tells us that having fewer CASes might be a good optimization.

> Both head and tail are permitted to lag.  In fact, failing to update them every time one could is a significant optimization (fewer CASes).
>   ...
>   Since head and tail are updated concurrently and independently, it is possible for tail to lag behind head (why not)?
>
> <sup>[JDK 8 > `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java#l149)</sup>

Note that the returned result of `size()` may be inaccurate, and, as they put it, "is typically not very useful in concurrent applications".

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andrew. Assuming you're quoting in the highlighted section, can you provide a link or reference?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. This helps.